# How to combine X_test, y test, and y predictions after text analytics prediction?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, concatenation

After using logitics Reg on text analytics, I was trying to combine the X_test, y_arr_test (label), and y_predictions to ONE dataframe, but don't know how to do it. Need help.

'''

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_arr_train)
X_train = vectorizer.transform(X_arr_train)
X_test  = vectorizer.transform(X_arr_test)
X_train
```

'''

'''

```
# logistic Reg
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_arr_train)
score = classifier.score(X_test, y_arr_test) 
y_predictions=classifier.predict(X_test)
```

'''

`X_test`
return: <1333x5676 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 26934 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

`np.shape(y_arr_test)`
return: (1333,)

Then I dont know how to put X_test, y_arr_test (label), and y_predictions to ONE dataframe. The goal is to show the wrong predictions and know why.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the existing df you can just add the prediction results like:

`x_train['preds'] = y_predictions`

same goes for labels like

`x_train['labels'] = y_train`

or all in one:

```py
new_df = x_train.copy()

new_df['preds'] = y_predictions
new_df['labels'] = y_train
```

have you tried this?